# Why does my for loop containing a simple while loop only run twice? And poorly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to loop over this `while` loop a few times to collect info about how long it takes to output the correct sequence of lines (to spell "CODER"). I expect my `for` loop to loop ten times. Instead, I only get one loop, and then one malfunctioning repetition done in 0 seconds.

I can replace the `for i in (0, 10)` line with a `while i < 10` and add a `i += 1` later on to get a longer piece of malfunctioning output (it will cycle the first conclusion to the while loop n times instead of 2 times). I also tried moving the lists and dictionary inside of the for loop but that didn't make the loop run properly.

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import datetime


stats_collection = []
correct_order = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  # A list of numbers between 0 and 4
output_order = []
iterations = 0
the_lines = {0: "...###.................#####...####..",
             1: "..#...#.........####...#.......#...#.",
             2: "..#.......###...#...#..##......##....",
             3: "..#...#..#...#..#...#..#.......#.#...",
             4: "...###....###...####...#####...#..#..",}

for i in (0,10):

    a_currentDT = str(datetime.datetime.now())

    while output_order[-5:] != correct_order:
        next = randint(0, 4) # Select between
        output_order.append(next)
        print(the_lines[next])
        iterations += 1
        # sleep(0.125)

    final_iterations = iterations

    b_currentDT = str(datetime.datetime.now())

    print("Finished!")
    print("Iterations: {num}".format(num=final_iterations))
    print(a_currentDT)
    print(b_currentDT)

    stats_collection.append(final_iterations)

print(stats_collection)
```

What I expect is something like a printed list from `print(stats_collection)` that is like: `[134, 2948, 4001, 598, 910, 1000, 2000, 3003, 10593, 403]` or another set of 10 numbers. But I only get the first run printed twice, or `n` times if I replace the `for` loop with a `while` loop (as in `while i < 10` or something).

Here is what output I get from `for i in (0, 10):` as the mechanism for looping over the `while` loop:

```
Finished!
Iterations: 8598
2019-06-02 15:21:21.543503
2019-06-02 15:21:21.641444
Finished!
Iterations: 8598
2019-06-02 15:21:21.641444
2019-06-02 15:21:21.641444
[8598, 8598]
```

I'm expecting the code to run the while loop a second time and have a completely different result, including a total of 10 different results, something like this:

```
Finished!
Iterations: 8598
2019-06-02 15:21:21.543503
2019-06-02 15:21:21.641444
Finished!
Iterations: 159
2019-06-02 15:21:21.641445
2019-06-02 15:21:21.700555
[8598, 159]
```

But ten different results of course.

The code would work great except for this miscellaneous error. I actually don't understand why the code is doing this whatsoever.

It may be useful to see that the second loop is actually done instantaneously. I don't know what's going on at all. Am I not able to host a `while` loop inside of a `for` loop like that?

Answer (score 4):

`for i in (0,10):` sets `i` to each of the elements of the tuple `(0, 10)` in turn.  Specifically, it means:

- Run the loop body with `i=0`
- Run the loop body with `i=10`
- Done.

If you want to loop over the range from 0 to (but not including) 10, you need to write:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
```

or just:

```
for i in range(10):
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. Solved.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems in your code:

1. `for i in (0,10)` should be `for i in range(0, 10)`, the former one iterates only 2 times, which `i = 0 and i = 10`.
2. You should move `output_order = []` and `iterations = 0` into `for-loop`, this is also why your results keep repeating, because `output_order` doesn't reset and it keeps solution after first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop has a 1 in 3125 chance of producing the appropriate order on each iteration.  It will take about 2000 iterations to have 50% chance of finding the proper order.  5000 iterations will have 80% chance of finding it. This should give random execution times but, as your code is tight now, it will only repeat the first results over and over.

Printing lines as you go will slow it down considerably.

Since you're not resetting output_order between samples, your second pass will find a matching result immediately (as reflected in the times) but will show the previous number of iterations since you're not resetting that variable either.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code a bit, as it seemed like you were performing a lot more repetitions than necessary. From what I understood of your specs, you want to compute how many repetitions it takes to spell coder. I changed the code to only move to the next line once the random integer matched the index of the current line to be printed.

```
`from random import randint
 from time import sleep
 import datetime


 stats_collection = []
 correct_order = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  # A list of numbers between 0 and 4
 iterations = 0
 the_lines = {0: "...###.................#####...####..",
         1: "..#...#.........####...#.......#...#.",
         2: "..#.......###...#...#..##......##....",
         3: "..#...#..#...#..#...#..#.......#.#...",
         4: "...###....###...####...#####...#..#..",}

for i in range(0,10):
    output_order = [None for i in range(len(correct_order))]

    a_currentDT = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    idx = 0
    while output_order != correct_order:
        next = randint(0, 4) # Select between
        if output_order[idx] == None and idx == next:
            output_order[idx] = next
            idx += 1
            print(the_lines[next])

        iterations += 1

        # sleep(0.125)
    print(output_order)

    final_iterations = iterations


    b_currentDT = str(datetime.datetime.now())

    print("Finished!")
    print("Iterations: {num}".format(num=final_iterations))
    print(a_currentDT)
    print(b_currentDT)

    stats_collection.append(final_iterations)
    iterations = 0

print(stats_collection)`
```

I also have a modified that matches most closely what you had in the beginning.

```
`from random import randint
from time import sleep
import datetime


stats_collection = []
correct_order = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  # A list of numbers between 0 and 4
iterations = 0
the_lines = {0: "...###.................#####...####..",
             1: "..#...#.........####...#.......#...#.",
             2: "..#.......###...#...#..##......##....",
             3: "..#...#..#...#..#...#..#.......#.#...",
             4: "...###....###...####...#####...#..#..",}

for i in range(0,10):
    output_order = []

    a_currentDT = str(datetime.datetime.now())

    while output_order[-5:] != correct_order:
        next = randint(0, 4) # Select between
        output_order.append(next)
        iterations += 1
        # print(the_lines[next])
        # sleep(0.125)
    # print(output_order[-5:])

    final_iterations = iterations


    b_currentDT = str(datetime.datetime.now())

    print("Finished!")
    print("Iterations: {num}".format(num=final_iterations))
    print(a_currentDT)
    print(b_currentDT)

    stats_collection.append(final_iterations)
    iterations = 0

print(stats_collection)`
```